# calculate subtotal for geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have the following table
Example 1:

```
L1lEVEL L1lEVEL Level 3                Amount
EMEA    France  France excl Midcaps     100
EMEA    France  Midcaps France         203
EMEA    Germany Germany                409
EMEA    Italie  Italie                 821
EMEA    Benelux Netherland            1645
EMEA    Benelux Belgium               3293
EMEA    UK       UK                   6589
EMEA    Iberia  Iberia              13181
Americas US      US                 26365
Americas CANADA CANADA               52733
```

I need to calculate total and subtotal specifically for EMEA: I've two subtotals Emea DM and EMEA EXL DM

- EMEA DM: France excl Midcaps , Italie , Belgium when Amount for Belgium  => 3000
- EMEA EXL DM: the level is other than France excl Midcaps , Italie , Belgium
  when Amount for Belgium  < 3000

when Amount for Belgium  > 3000

```
EMEA    100+203+09+8211645+3293+6589+131181
```

Emea DM 203+821+3293

```
EMEA EXL DM:    EMEA -EMEA DM
```

Example 2:

```
 L1lEVEL    L1lEVEL Level 3                Amount
    EMEA    France  France excl Midcaps     100
    EMEA    France  Midcaps France         203
    EMEA    Germany Germany                409
    EMEA    Italie  Italie                 821
    EMEA    Benelux Netherland            1645
    EMEA    Benelux Belgium               10
    EMEA    UK       UK                   6589
    EMEA    Iberia  Iberia              13181
    Americas US      US                 26365
    Americas CANADA CANADA               52733
```

when Amount for Belgium = 10 < 3000

```
EMEA    100+203+09+8211645+3293+6589+131181

Emea DM 203+821

EMEA EXL DM:    EMEA -EMEA DM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can do conditional aggregation. A lateral join comes handy to avoid repeating the conditional expressions:

```
select
    sum(amount) emea,
    sum(case when region = 'EMEA DM'     then amount else 0 end) as emea_dm,
    sum(case when region = 'EMEA EXL DM' then amount else 0 end) as emea_exl_dm
from mytable t
cross apply (values (
    case when (level2 = 'France' and level3 = 'France excl Midcaps') 
        or level3 = 'Italie'
        or (level3 = 'Belgium' and amount > 3000)
    then 'EMEA DM' else 'EMEA EXL DM' end
)) as x(region)
where t.level1 = 'EMEA'
```

Your question is not very clear about the names of the columns; I assumed `level1`, `level2` and `level3`.